# What is $\|a\|=\max_{f \in A^\ast}|f(a)|$?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I would like to ask if the norm

$$\|a\|=\max_{f \in A^\ast}|f(a)|$$

has a name (where $A$ is a Banach space and $A^\ast$ denotes the continuous dual) and how to prove this equality. This equality is given in [these lecture notes](http://www.math.ksu.edu/~nagy/real-an/2-05-b-alg.pdf) in exercise 13 on page 97.
 Also is the $1$ in the expression $\max_{f \in (A^\ast)_1}|f(a)|$ in the notes a typo? If not, what does it mean?

Comment: If you let $f$ range through all of $A^\ast$, then $\sup\limits_{f\in A^\ast} \lvert f(a)\rvert = \infty$ for all $a\neq 0$. If you constrain $f$ to have norm $\leqslant 1$, it is just the norm on $A$ you started with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all it is not correct. The correct version is
$$
\|a\|=\sup_{\substack{f\in A^*,\\ \|f\|_*=1}}|f(a)|
$$
I think it is call "star-norm". (In my language at least.)

The "$\ge$" is obvious. In order to prove the "$\le$" part you need Hahn-Banach, which guarantees the existence of $f\in A^*$, which $f(a)=|a|$ and $\|f\|_*=1$.

Comment: I can't find a reference to the terminology "star-norm" with Google. Are you sure there would be a term for a norm which is the same as the original norm? At least, this result says that the "dual norm" of the "dual norm" is equal to the original norm. That is the canonical isometric embedding of every normed space into its bidual. (And the sup is indeed a max, as you showed)